# What happens if I don't use all of my votes in the third phase of an election?

Tags: support, moderator-election

In the third phase of an election<sup>1</sup>, the yellow box on the right says (emphasis mine) that

> Each voter may select **up to** three candidates

and that

> We will calculate the winners using OpaVote with the Meek STV method, which automatically weights users' votes **in the way that does the most good for the candidates they have selected**, in order of preference.

So I can cast 3 votes, but let's say I only cast one. Does that make it "stronger"? Would it be similar to giving 3 votes to that candidate, or, equivalently, choosing him/her as first, second and third option (which can't be done)?
Or would I simply cast a normal vote, thus wasting my other 2?

---

<sup>1</sup>On a side note: can we find a better name for the third phase? I mean, an election has three phases, called "Nomination", "Primary", and... 
"Election". So if I talk about "election", am I talking about the general process, including all three phases, or just the last one? Can't we call the third one something like "Final election"? I realise this is not a great name either, but maybe someone can come up with something better...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### You do not get three votes! You only get one vote.

You can indicate as many as three people to receive it in order of preference. Choosing additional people doesn't water down your vote for the first because you only ever vote for them if your first choice is completely eliminated (or if your first choice is elected with a surplus of votes, your second or third choice will get a fraction of that single vote).

If you only choose one person and that person gets eliminated, your vote will go into the "exhausted" bin, meaning that your vote ends up not going towards deciding who wins the election.

If you only choose one person and that person is selected, then at least a fraction of your vote will still be counted and the remainder will be considered "exhausted".

If, however, you chose two or three candidates, your vote would be transferred to the second candidate if the first choice is eliminated or, if the first is elected, that fraction that they didn't need to win would be transferred.

There's a few great explanations of how the voting process works on Meta Stack Exchange: [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)